# Pandas is converting month 10 into month 1. Is there a format issue here?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, datetime-format

I have the following DataFrame

```
    data  inflation
0   2000.01       0.62
1   2000.02       0.13
2   2000.03       0.22
3   2000.04       0.42
4   2000.05       0.01
5   2000.06       0.23
6   2000.07       1.61
7   2000.08       1.31
8   2000.09       0.23
9   2000.10       0.14
```

Note that the format of the Year Month is with a dot
When I try to convert to DateTime as in:

```
inflation.data = pd.to_datetime(inflation.data, format='%Y.%m')
```

I get both line 0 and line 9 as `2000-01-01`

That means pandas is automatically changing .10 into .01

Is that a bug? or just a format issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're actually using the formatting codes in pandas slightly incorrectly.

Look at the Pandas [helpfile](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html#)

> pandas.to_datetime(*args, **kwargs)[source]
>
> Convert argument to datetime.
>
> Parameters:
>
> arg : string, datetime, list, tuple, 1-d array, Series

you appear to be feeding it float64s when it probably expects strings

Try the following code.

Or convert your `inflation.data` to string (use `inflation.data.apply(str)`)

```
 f0=['2000.01',
   '2000.02',
   '2000.03',
   '2000.04',
   '2000.05',
   '2000.06',       
   '2000.07',       
   '2000.08',       
   '2000.09',
   '2000.10']
 inflation=pd.DataFrame(f0,columns={'data'})
 inflation.data=pd.to_datetime(inflation.data,format='%Y.%m')
```

**output**

```
Out[3]: 
0   2000-01-01
1   2000-02-01
2   2000-03-01
3   2000-04-01
4   2000-05-01
5   2000-06-01
6   2000-07-01
7   2000-08-01
8   2000-09-01
9   2000-10-01
Name: data, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Answer (score 1):

This is an interesting problem. The astype() construct is converting .10 to .01 and you can't use any split methods on the current float type.
Here is my take on this:
Use python math module modf function which returns the fractional and integer parts of x.
Now round the year and month data and convert to string for to_datetime to interpret.

```
import math

df['Year']= df.data.apply(lambda x: round(math.modf(x)[1])).astype(str)
df['Month']= df.data.apply(lambda x: round((math.modf(x)[0])*100)).astype(str)
df = df.drop('data', axis = 1)
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df.Year+':'+df.Month, format = '%Y:%m')
df = df.drop(['Year', 'Month'], axis = 1)
```

You get

```
    inflation   Date
0   0.62        2000-01-01
1   0.13        2000-02-01
2   0.22        2000-03-01
3   0.42        2000-04-01
4   0.01        2000-05-01
5   0.23        2000-06-01
6   1.61        2000-07-01
7   1.31        2000-08-01
8   0.23        2000-09-01
9   0.14        2000-10-01
```